# Can't drag dynamically added DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a DIV with id: TEST that I can drag using jQuery UI. All works, but as soon as I remove it and load the DIV into the HTML dynamically (well to specify more: using SSE to load the DIV into the HTML), the DIV can't be dragged. This is because the jQuery is loaded before the DIV is. How to fix this? Since I use SSE, the DIV is loaded several times over a period of time.

The jquery code:

```
 $(function() {
      $( "#TEST" ).draggable({ 
         containment: "parent"             
      }).css({'cursor': 'all-scroll', 'z-index': '5'});
 });
```

The DIV TEST is loaded into antoher DIV called dragZone

```
<div id="dragZone" name="dragZone"> [div TEST is loaded here] </div>
```

The JS that loads the SSE:

```
 //HTML5 SSE(Server Sent Event) initilization
     this.initSevr=function(){
          sevr = new EventSource('test.php');
          sevr.onmessage = function(e){ 
              if(oldata!=e.data){
                  dragZone.innerHTML+=e.data;
                  oldata = e.data;
              }
          };     
     };
```

So how can I drag the DIV again? The Div is put into the HTML using SSE, this all works.

Comment: Your jquery is probably being called before you inject that test div, so its not binding the draggable to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to move your draggable code into the loading event, like this:

```
 //HTML5 SSE(Server Sent Event) initilization
     this.initSevr=function(){
          sevr = new EventSource('test.php');
          sevr.onmessage = function(e){ 
              if(oldata!=e.data){
                  dragZone.innerHTML+=e.data;
                  oldata = e.data;

                  $( "#TEST" ).draggable({ 
                     containment: "parent"             
                  }).css({'cursor': 'all-scroll', 'z-index': '5'});
              }
          };     
     };
```

This is assuming the DOM is updated immediately after innerHTML is used; if not it may be necessary to use a short setTimeout to make it draggable.

Comment: I'll try this, I wasn't aware you could put jquery code in there :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot a quote, try to change from

```
sevr = new EventSource('test.php);
```

to

```
sevr = new EventSource('test.php');
```

Comment: indeed a typo (was too fast copy pasting), but that isn't the problem here, thanks brining it to my attention, fixed it